# convert sqlite database to SQLAnywhere?

Tags: sql, blackberry

is their any tools to convert SQLLite database to SQLAnywhere format ?,the purpose to use SQLLite on BlackBerry devices with software version less than 5

Comment: indeed, I'd love to answer-- but you don't seem to accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to export the data as INSERT script and then load it on SQLAnywhere.